# ruby gem for news parsing snippets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, rubygems

I'm using https://github.com/dejan/auto_html for generating the HTML pertaining to media files, does anyone know of anything similar for parsing news stories?

I basically want to do something like Facebook does when you post a URL and it grabs the relevant snippet and image, etc.

I could do this myself but considering the different standards... opengraph, rss, etc. I figured something like this might already exist.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I actually wrote something for this a while back using oEmbed. The gem is called [oembed_links](https://github.com/netshade/oembed_links) and it will check with oEmbed providers on the appropriate way to embed a resource.  It may accomplish what you need.

The original "best" oEmbed domain, oohembed, seems to now be owned by a company called [embed.ly](http://embed.ly/) which may also be of interest you.